# ReactJS : running jQuery on div in component after updating

Tags: jquery, reactjs, updating

Bit of a tricky one is this.

I have a parent component that contains a load of child divs, each child representing an entity with an image and rating, with the ratings coming from the server, using [Raty](https://wbotelhos.com/raty). The rating (score) is accessible in the **data-score** attribute and Raty needs to be run to grab this score and render the rating bar accordingly. I am assuming this needs to be run in the componentDidUpdate() event.

I would like to know the best way to approach this. Would it be simply to get the ID of the parent div and tell jQuery to iterate all the child divs and then render each rating based on the **data-score** attribute or is there a way to use specific React IDs to tell jQuery the exact ID of the element to run Raty against?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to do it is to get references to the divs using the "ref" attribute in ReactJS:

```
const MyComponent = React.createClass({
   render() {
       return (
           <div>
               <div ref={ this.captureFirstDiv } />
               <div ref={ this.captureSecondDiv } />
           </div>
       );
   },

   captureFirstDiv( firstDiv ) { this.firstDiv = firstDiv; },
   captureSecondDiv( secondDiv ) { this.secondDiv = secondDiv; },

   componentDidUpdate( ) {
       $( this.firstDiv ).raty();
       $( this.secondDiv ).raty();
   }
});
```

The problem with this approach is that ReactJS may get very cross with you for messing around with the DOM. If that happens, I suggest creating a Raty React component wrapper that never updates (by setting shouldComponentUpdate() to always return false).

Comment: Thanks for your help. In the end, I just ended up a component for each child div and running .raty() in the componentDidMount() event. A very simple solution but I ended getting their in a roundabout manner.